# DMZ com Ajax no cliente

Tags: angularjs

Meu problema é o seguinte, venho desenvolvendo uma `Single-Page Application` que no final, será postada em um servidor `DMZ`. Do outro lado terei uma `API` que receberá as requisições do meu `front`, o problema é :  o meu cliente terá uma cópia do front na sua máquina, e ao fazer a requisição terei de liberar minha rede local (onde está a `API`), tornando o conceito de `DMZ` só **50%**.

Alguém já teve esse problema ? Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Coloque sua API na DMZ. Implemente um serviço na rede local que estabeleça um canal de comunicação com a API - Messaging Queue, Conexão TCP LAN -> DMZ, etc. Roteie requisições pelo canal.

Comment: Algum artigo ou tutorial que explique isso @Ibotinelly? É algo novo para mim e uma maioria. Poderia ser legal fazer uma pergunta e responder a mesma somente sobre esse assunto.

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian postado como resposta, obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 2):

Por DMZ eu entendo que você tem um segmento de rede apenas com conexões entrantes e limitações a serviços que podem ser explorados como vetores de acesso. Assim sendo, uma implementação viável segue o seguinte modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde:

- Requisições são recebidas, na DMZ, por uma API que faz o papel de broker/proxy;
- Esta API implementa um modelo de *Messaging Queue* - MSMQ, ZeroMQ ou outro similar;
- A API envia requisições de serviço via MQ, e aguarda um status de resposta;
- Na rede local, também monitorando a mesma MQ, está um serviço;
- Ao receber uma requisição, este serviço o processa; caso necessário, envia um status/payload de retorno;
- A API processa o retorno e o envia para o cliente.

Comment: Nesse caso, qual a real vantagem de utilizar o Message Queue? Eu poderia implementar no lugar dele outra API que retornaria os dados na camada de LAN.